# "PDF" file generation using PowerBI

Tags: asp.net, powerbi

There is requirement in our project. Where we want to generate PDF based report. How to generate PDF based report using Power BI in ASP.NET?

Comment: If you need it in web then ,
First you have to generate report as general you creating it then do share as PDF as below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-pdf

Comment: Using Power BI desktop You can export report in PDF